# SSL redirect issues

Tags: iptables, apache-httpd, ssl

Have issues trying to redirect port 443 to either port 444 or 445. This is only for the inside of my network; 444 and 445 are dropped at the firewall incoming on the Wan connection. What I am trying to accomplish is to display a short/quick messages to our local users. One messages if for those younger users that should be in bed, the other is for devices on the network we do not know ( friend brings in a cell or tablet and connects to our wifi ). If they try to surf to port 80 ( not ssl ) everything works OkieDokie and whichever message is displayed.
Here is the firewall redirect for that.

```
iptables -t nat -A EndOfNet -i $Lan1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 82
iptables -t nat -A EndOfNet -i $Lan1 -p tcp --dport 82 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.100.254
```

Pretty much the same code for SSL redirect; except I get "Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG"

```
iptables -t nat -A EndOfNet -i $Lan1 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 445
iptables -t nat -A EndOfNet -i $Lan1 -p tcp --dport 445 -j DNAT --to-destination [WanIP]
```

Note that I did not include port 81 or 444 in the iptables code above for brevity.
Certs are installed and work properly for port 443; either inside or outside my network. VirtualHost in httpd config:

```
<VirtualHost *:444>
 ServerName Alias.FQDN.TLD
 Redirect / https://Alias.FQDN.TLD
 ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/RedirectErr.log"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:445>
 ServerName Alias.FQDN.TLD
 Redirect / https://ALias.FQDN.TLD
 ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/RedirectErr.log"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost    192.168.100.254:81>
    DocumentRoot    "/var/www/html/Special/Unknown"
    ServerName  192.168.100.254
    ErrorLog    "/var/log/httpd/Error.log"
  CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/Unknown.log" combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost    192.168.100.254:82>
    DocumentRoot    "/var/www/html/Special/EndInet"
    ServerName  192.168.100.254
    ErrorLog    "/var/log/httpd/Error.log"
    CustomLog   "/var/log/httpd/EndInet.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I played with ssl.conf and tried to add port 444 and 445 of which "port already in use" error showed when I restarted httpd. I suspect that cause is the VirtualHost config for 444 and 445 in httpd.vhosts.conf

`dig -x [WanIP]` shows the proper Alias.FQDN.TLD now as I found it pointed to a local machine of which I got a SSL "name(s) do not match" or something like that.

Is redirecting via port in SSL possible? If so, what am I missing?

Thanks!

Ulrich -
Listen in httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
Listen 80
Listen 81
Listen 82
Listen 444 https
Listen 445 https
```

Listen 443 is in ssl.conf

Answer (score 0):

`SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG` can happen if you attempt to speak https to a port that answers http. Did you do `Listen 444` or `Listen 444 https` in your config? By default, 443 is the only port where httpd will know to speak https by default.

Answer (score -1):

Geesh! Not enough coffee???

I had a redirect for both 444 and 445 in httpd-vhosts.conf. Didn't need to do the redirect as those ports are in ssl.conf. Removed the redirect and it now works.

Can ya say brain-fart?

todh